# how to improve grep efficiency in perl when the file number is huge

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I want to grep some log information from the log files located in the following directory structure using perl:
`$jobDir/jobXXXX/host.log` where `XXXX` is a job number, from 1 to a few thousands. There's no other kinds of sub directory under `$jobDir` and no other files except logs under `jobXXXX`. The script is :

```
my  @Info;  #store the log informaiton
my $Num = 0;
@Info = qx(grep "information" -r $jobDir); #is this OK ?

foreach(@Info){
        if($_=~ /\((\d+)\)(.*)\((\d+)\)/){
            Output(xxxxxxxx);   
        }
        $Num=$Num+1; #number count      
    }
```

It is found that when then job number is a few thousands,  this script will take very long time to output the information.

Is there any way to improve its efficiency?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post a short sample of the `host.log`?

Comment: Hi @Tuga  sorry, since the log is kind of related to my company's product I may not able to provide the log. Is it possibly related to the content of the log? Each log will be a few thousands lines and the  "information" is distributed randomly.

Comment: You could replace `.*` with `(?>[^(\n]++|\((?!\d+\)))*`

Comment: what is a "very long time"?  have you tested to see if it is your grep that is taking the time or the stuff after it?  (how long does just the grep command with `>/dev/null` take?)

Answer (score 5):

You should search those log file one by one, and scan each log file line by line, instead of reading the output of `grep` to memory (that could cost lots of memory, and slow your program, even your system):

```
# untested script

my $Num;
foreach my $log (<$jobDir/job*/host.log>) {
    open my $logfh, '<', "$log" or die "Cannot open $log: $!";
    while (<$logfh>) {
        if (m/information/) {
            if(m/\((\d+)\)(.*)\((\d+)\)/) {
                Output(xxx);
            }
            $Num++;
        }
    }
    close $logfh;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

While it would be more elegant to use the matching built into perl (see the other answer), calling the `grep` command can be more efficient and faster, especially if there are lots of data but only few matches. But the way you call it is to first run grep and collect all data, and then scan through all the data. This will need more memory because you first collect all data, and you have to wait for the output until all data are collected. Better would be to output as soon as the first data are collected:

```
open( my $fh,'-|','grep',"information",'-r',$jobDir) or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
    if(/\((\d+)\)(.*)\((\d+)\)/){
        Output(xxxxxxxx);
    }
    $Num=$Num+1; #number count      
}
```